# Creating a dropdownlist from your controller or view model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

How would I create a SelectList in my controller and pass it to my view?  I need to give the "-- Select --" option a value of 0.

I'm responding to the [replies that I got from Jeremey of Fluent Validation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/discussions/264776).

This is what I currently have.  My view model:

```
[Validator(typeof(CreateCategoryViewModelValidator))]
public class CreateCategoryViewModel
{
    public CreateCategoryViewModel()
    {
        IsActive = true;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string MetaKeywords { get; set; }
    public string MetaDescription { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public IList<Category> ParentCategories { get; set; }
    public int ParentCategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

My controller.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    List<Category> parentCategoriesList = categoryService.GetParentCategories();

    CreateCategoryViewModel createCategoryViewModel = new CreateCategoryViewModel
    {
        ParentCategories = parentCategoriesList
    };

    return View(createCategoryViewModel);
}
```

This is what I have in my view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ParentCategoryId, new SelectList(Model.ParentCategories, "Id", "Name", Model.ParentCategoryId), "-- Select --")
```

How do I create a dropdown list in the controller or view model and pass it to the view?  I need the "-- Select --" option to have a value of 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your model, change the `IList<Category>` to `SelectList` and then instantiate it like this...

```
List<ParentCategory> parentCategories = categoryService.GetParentCategories();

parentCategories.Insert(0, new ParentCategory(){ Id = "0", Name = "--Select--"});

ParentCategories = new SelectList(parentCategories, "Id", "Name");
```

Then in your view you can simply call

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ParentCategoryId, Model.ParentCategories);
```

Comment: I need the "-- Select --" option have a value of 0.  Where does it state this in your code??

Comment: Sorry, I missed that bit. Why do you need it to have a value of 0?

Comment: I'm using Fluent Validation.  Jeremy says that I need to have a select option with a value of 0 otherwise my ModelState will always be false if I don't select a value in the dropdown.

Comment: That's right, you just need to insert a new `ParentCategory` into the top of the list. I will edit my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

One way I've seen it done is to create an object to wrap the id and value of the drop down item, like a `List<SelectValue>`, and pass it in your ViewModel to the view and then use an HTML helper to construct the dropdown.

```
public class SelectValue
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Id of the dropdown value
    /// </summary>
    public int Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Display string for the Dropdown
    /// </summary>
    public string DropdownValue { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the view model:

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    public List<SelectValue> DropDownValues {get; set;}
}
```

Here is the HTML Helper:

```
public static SelectList CreateSelectListWithSelectOption(this HtmlHelper helper, List<SelectValue> options, string selectedValue)
{
    var values = (from option in options
                  select new { Id = option.Id.ToString(), Value = option.DropdownValue }).ToList();

    values.Insert(0, new { Id = 0, Value = "--Select--" });

    return new SelectList(values, "Id", "Value", selectedValue);
}
```

Then in your view you call the helper:

```
@Html.DropDownList("DropDownListName", Html.CreateSelectListWithSelect(Model.DropDownValues, "--Select--"))
```