# Creating an auto-generated DropDownList on View from ViewModel

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Which I'd expect to be implemented in .NET MVC, but trying to figure out how to actually do it. Currently on my ViewModel, I have (for example):

```
public class GroupPolicyViewModel
{
   public int PolicyId { get; set; }
   public int HistoryId{ get; set; }
   public SelectList ProductList { get; set; } // tried this
   public List<Product> ProductList1 { get; set; } // tried this
}
```

Whenever I try and auto-generate my View from this ViewModel, the ProductList gets ignored. Is there any way to auto-generate a DropDownList at all from the ViewModel?

Comment: This may be of help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663615/creating-a-dropdownlist-from-your-controller-or-view-model

Comment: Unfortunately that still means I have to create the DropDownListFor manually in my View. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With model

```
public class GroupPolicyViewModel
{
   public int PolicyId { get; set; }
   public int HistoryId{ get; set; }
   public int SelectedProductId{ get; set; }   
   public List<Product> ProductList { get; set; } 
}
```

You can create DropDownList

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedProductId, 
                  new SelectList(Model.ProductList, "ProductId", "ProductName"))
```

Or if you have SelectList of products in your model

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedProductId, Model.ProductSelectList)
```

If you want some generated code, you need to use scaffolding option with providing data context class. Here is nice tutorial [MVC Music Store](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-5)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what I'm trying to accomplish is the @Html.DropDownListFor being created for me in my View (auto generated - Add View in Visual Studio). Is this possible?

Comment: Inside your view, don't forget to specify your model as GroupPolicyViewModel.

Answer (score 2):

You can (from VS2010) when creating a new Controller and using Entity Framework.  Specify in the wizard to include Entity Framework and Read/Write ops and the wizard will create both the controller and the views.

[image]

It'll generate code like this [there is more] in the controller:

```
   public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.CostCentre_ID = new SelectList(db.CostCentres, "ID", "Name");
        ViewBag.Location_ID = new SelectList(db.Locations, "ID", "Name");
        ViewBag.User_ID = new SelectList(db.UCMUsers, "User_ID", "EmployeeNo");
        return View();
    }
```

and this in the view:

```
<div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("User_ID", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User_ID)
 </div>
```